# Jena Java Api to read RDF file?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have a rdf file which has format:

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:geo="xyz"
xmlns:quality="xyz"
xmlns:purl="xyz"
xmlns:swrlb="xyz"> 

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="title1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="resource22"/>
<info:contains>fromdisk1</info:contains>
<info:has_text_value>
The location 
</info:has_text_value>
  </rdf:Description>
```

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="title2">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="resource12"/>
<info:contains>fromdisk2</info:contains>
<info:has_text_value>
xyz 
   </info:has_text_value>
  </rdf:Description>

  </rdf:RDF>
```

I want to store the values of info:has_text_value and the corresponding info:contains. I have tried a lot of ways with JENA API but have not been successful. Could you please guide how i can do that. Any source code would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to write, read and querying RDF with JENA [here](http://jena.sourceforge.net/tutorial/RDF_API/index.html).

Answer (score 9):

If this is a representative sample of your RDF, there are a couple of problems with it:

- You **should not** assert that all of the prefixes are `xyz`. When you use a shortened name, such as `info:contains` or `geo:something`, the actual URI being used to identify the resource is the *concatenation* of the namespace URI and the local name. Properly used, namespace URI's can disambiguate what would otherwise be similarly named concepts, for example `computers:monitor` and `reptiles:monitor` might be intended to represent a display screen and a lizard, respectively. However, if both `computers` and `reptiles` namespaces have the same value, then both URI's denote the same resource and every statement made about one resource is also made about the other. Not a good idea.
- Your sample is incomplete because the `info` namespace is not defined, so `info:contains` does not denote a legal property URI.
- The resource `title2` has a *relative URI*, i.e. what it denotes is relative to the base URI of the document. This means that, for example, if you read the file containing the document from a different location (e.g. on disk or from an `http:` URL), the identity of `title2` *will change*. You can mitigate this effect by asserting the base URI of the document by adding an `xml:base` statement.

Fixing these problems (and making guesses about your namespaces), gets:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:geo="http://example.org/schema/geo#"
  xmlns:quality="http://example.org/schema/quality#"
  xmlns:purl="http://example.org/schema/purl#"
  xmlns:swrlb="http://example.org/schema/swrlb#"
  xmlns:info="http://example.org/schema/info#"
  xml:base="http://example.org/data/test#"
> 

<rdf:Description rdf:about="title1">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="resource22"/>
  <info:contains>fromdisk1</info:contains>
  <info:has_text_value>The location</info:has_text_value>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="title2">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="resource12"/>
  <info:contains>fromdisk2</info:contains>
  <info:has_text_value>xyz</info:has_text_value>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

There are lots of online resources to show you how to read and manipulate RDF data in Jena. To get you started, here is **one** way of doing so:

First create a `Model` and load your data into. I'll assume that your data is in the file `./rdf/test.rdf`:

```
Model m = FileManager.get().loadModel( "./rdf/test.rdf" );
```

Now create a resource denoting `title2`:

```
String NS = "http://example.org/data/test#";
Resource title2 = m.getResource( NS + "title2" );
```

Now list the properties of the resource:

```
for (StmtIterator i = title2.listProperties(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement s = i.next();
    System.out.println( "title2 has property " + s.getPredicate() + 
                        " with value " + s.getObject() );
}
```

Alternatively, create a property object to access the `info:contains` property:

```
Property contains = m.getProperty( NS + "contains" );
System.out.println( "title2.contains = " + title2.getProperty( contains )
                                                 .getObject();
```

Comment: i am sorry for xyz but i had to change them from read rdf because of the nature of the data. Also sir, the title 1 and 2 have been changed, in real data they are urls about which i cant know from before. Is there a way to get the list of those uri?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you won't know in advance the URI's of the resources you want to examine. Presumably those resources will have some characteristics that you will use to identify them. How will you know which resources you want to process? Can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: Can you email me at mbansal2@buffalo.edu. I will send you a copy of the real rdf file. This thing is really important for me so if you could help you would do me a great favor. If you donot want to send me email you can let me know and i will publish the rdf here(not preferred though because of the nature of the material).

Comment: I have tried adding the whole rdf file as comment but the stackoverflow is not letting me even a part of it because of the number of characters in the file. Can i get the file some other way, either you can email me your email address and i will send the file or you can tell me some other place to post it so that it can get to you. I really need your guidance on this. Thanks

Comment: My email address is listed on my StackOverflow profile page. If you send me the file, I will look at it but probably not until Monday as I'll be out all day on Sunday.